# How to create a form with variable no. of field set

Tags: asp.net, html

I have to design a page for user information, for some background verification purpose, at my work. I need a set of fields for address, total count of which will be selected by user to update the form with that many fields. So, if user selects 3, form will have 3 set of address fields. Similar concept for work and education details.

Right now, I am passing the count to a handler page, which checks total count, and return it along with querystring, back to the main page. I am able to update the no. of fields, this way, but, all values are lost, once I return to the form. There are a lot of fields to even use session object for every value. Also, it resets the count of other such field set to 0. So, if I select 4 in address field, it renders four set of address fields, but fields for other details are gone.

I need to know, if it is possible to update the fields, using just one page, instead of creating a handler file to handle the redirect, so that I don't lose other data.

Sorry, for sounding a bit confusing. Will update the question, if needed.

Edit:

[image: This is the screenshot of the address block.]

Similar blocks are there for education and work details. I want the update button to update the block, with that many fields, while retaining the values already entered by the user.

I have finally shifted the update code to one page. And the total count of blocks, is calculated by this way.

```
if request.form("addresscount") <> "" then
varaddresscount = request.form("addresscount")
else 
varaddresscount = 1
end if
```

varaddresscount is used to loop through the html code which renders address fields. Even with this method, if I click on update button to change the total field count, every value entered by user is reset to default. Is there a way to retain the no. of fields without using session object, as there are way too many fields for which I have to store the value in session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not have just a "add address" button that, whenever clicked, adds a extra set of input boxes using Javascript? That solves a lot of your problems regarding retaining the data on already filled in fields AND it makes it easier for the user.

Comment: That is exactly what I want, but I don't know how to do that. Do you mean, creating a button and calling a function which write the extra set? Well, let me try that too.

Comment: That works better. Only problem, it works only with javascript, and that too on server side. On client side, it gives error. Also, I have a couple variables to populate two fields out of the set, which I am not sure how to do now, as inline scripting won't work.